# Users REST API not working?

Tags: rest-api

My site has 8 users:

`All (8) | Administrator (2) | Subscriber (2) | Customer (1) | Vendor (3)`

When I go to `mysite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users` I only see one user, admin. There are even two admin users on my site but it only shows one.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `wp/v2/wp_users` is not a native endpoint. The correct endpoint is `wp/v2/users`. Is that what you're using? Or have you created your own endpoint?

Comment: Sorry that was the url I meant. I've edited the post. I am not a WP developer I am just consuming the API, I haven't created an endpoint.

Comment: Can you share the full code/URL you're using to make the request? Or are you just opening that URL in the browser?

Comment: Just opening it in the browser. I've also tried it in postman, passing a cookie parameter (/users?cookie=adflkjafg.....cookie)